# ARM NEON: How do I bit-shift a whole 64-bit d register?

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I want to logically left or right shift a `d` register (64-bit) by an arbitrary number of bits, with the count in another register.  (Not an assemble-time constant.)

It contains integer values and what I need to do is, to "move" them to the right position inside the register.  Only zeros should be shifted into the register at the "ends", so this is a logical shift, not arithmetic.

I want to shift the whole register without any element boundaries.

I have thought about using `vshl` and `vshr`, but they shift the register as separate SIMD elements and not the whole register as one "value".

Comment: For starters, you should specify what kind of shift. Integer or floating point?
 Bits, bytes or vector elements? What direction? What have you found in the reference manual and why is it not sufficient? As of now, it's a poor question.

Comment: thanks @JohannesSchaub-litb for the feedback, i tried to correct and specify my question.

Comment: I'm not experienced enough to answer. But I had a quick look into the manual and found VTRN, vector transpose. Is it sufficient?

Comment: I think you're asking for a shift of the whole register with no element boundaries.  But it's not clear if your shift count is always a whole number of bytes, or if it can be an arbitrary number of bits.  Also whether you need the shift-count to be a runtime variable, or if it can be a compile-time constant.

Comment: yes @PeterCordes that is exactly what i need. I just wasn't able to put it to words. my shift-count is a runtime variable and on bit level, not byte level

Comment: So [edit] your question to say that.

Answer (score 2):

While looking up exactly [how `vshl` works](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489g/CIHGHGAB.html), I see there's a version that uses 64-bit element size.

If you'd wanted to bit-shift a whole 128-bit `q` register, you'd have a problem, but `vshl` / `vshr` can do what you want for `d` registers, if you use the `u64`-datatype version.

```
vshl.u64  d1, d0,  d7      @  d1 = d1<<d7
```

Also available with `q` operands, to operate on two packed 64-bit values in parallel.

> VSHL (Vector Shift Left by signed variable) takes each element in a vector, shifts them by a value from the least significant byte of the corresponding element of a second vector, and places the results in the destination vector. **If the shift value is positive, the operation is a left shift. Otherwise, it is a right shift.**

For immediate shifts, there are separate mnemonics for left and right.  (e.g. [`vshr.u64 Dd, Dm, #imm`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489g/CIHGHGAB.html) vs. [`vshl.u64 Dd, Dm, #imm`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489g/CIHGHGAB.html)).  That may just be different assembler-syntax for a positive or negative immediate for the same opcode, though.